# Publish aspnet core web app in azure app service linux

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

I am trying to deploy an aspnet core web app in the Linux App service plan.The deployment is complete but I can't get my app from browser.When I go to KUDU I can see the files deployed properly. I tried the same with Windows App service Plan it works fine. I am not sure if I am missing any step. I tried to do it both from Azure DevOps and also from Visual studio code. I am happy to share my KUDU wwwroot information just to show the files deployed.

Comment: I wrote a PowerShell to remove all the files but still, the default page exists.so any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't done this already (From your comment above PowerShell script), please specify a startup script for the type of app you are running > Under App Service > Configuration> General Settings.

For .Net core, you need to set - the compiled DLL name as dotnet .dll
These commands or scripts are executed after the built-in Docker container is started, but before your application code is started.Checkout this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/containers/app-service-linux-faq#built-in-images) for more details.

[image]

Also, leverage "Diagnostic and solve problems" to fetch more details on the issue.

The default document is the web page that appears at the root URL for a website. The first matching file in the list is used. If the app uses modules that redirect based on the URL instead of providing static content, there is no need for standard documents.

You may update the application settings to the following and then check:

WEBSITE_DYNAMIC_CACHE — 0

WEBSITE_LOCAL_CACHE_OPTION- Never

- For staging enable this else app will be cached and will not refresh on publishing.

WEBSITE_WEBDEPLOY_USE_SCM — false

- Set false else you will not be able to use VS to publish directly.

Note that any changes you make outside the /home directory are stored in the container itself and don't persist beyond an app restart.

Comment: Thanks Ajay. I had already set the app settings. Let me try one more time with dotnet app dll also set.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the exact same problem.

This question pointed me at the right place. The below shows where the missing part is

[image]